# Drag & Drop в QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt5

Не могу разобраться в том, как работает drag & drop в qt-ишной model-view. Мне нужно реализовать перетаскивание между двумя `view` (QTreeView) в которых находятся разные модели (но с данными одного типа). Элементы захватываются в одном `view` и перетаскиваются во второй:

```
ui_->componentsView->setDragDropMode(
  QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode::DragOnly);
ui_->componentsView->setDragEnabled(true);

ui_->devicesView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode::DropOnly);
ui_->devicesView->setAcceptDrops(true);
ui_->devicesView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

При этоп "дропнуть" данные мы можем только в уже существующий элемент второй модели, данные в котором изменяться соответствующим образом:

```
bool DeviceModelAdapter::canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
                                         Qt::DropAction /*action*/,
                                         int /*row*/,
                                         int /*column*/,
                                         const QModelIndex &parent) const {
  if (auto mimeData = dynamic_cast<const NodeMimeData *>(data);
      mimeData && parent.isValid()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

QStringList DeviceModelAdapter::mimeTypes() const {
  return {NodeMimeData::mimeType()};// перетаскиваемый тип, содержит
 // указатели на некоторые объеты, которые добавятся к объетку, хранимому в модели
}

Qt::ItemFlags DeviceModelAdapter::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
  if (index.isValid()) {
    return ModelAdapter::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
  }
  return {};
}

bool DeviceModelAdapter::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
                                    Qt::DropAction /*action*/,
                                    int row,
                                    int /*column*/,
                                    const QModelIndex &parent) {
  if (auto nodeData = dynamic_cast<const NodeMimeData *>(data);
      nodeData && !parent.isValid()) {
    auto curIndex = index(row, 0);
    if (auto node = getNodeFromIndex(curIndex)) {
      for (auto &i : nodeData->ptrList()) {
        if (i) {
          i->setParent(node);
        }
      }
    }
    emit dataChanged(curIndex, curIndex);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Однако при навелении курсора на элемент в модели (куда должен происходить drop) курсор показывает, что невозможно дропнуть данные. При этом если в методе `canDropMimeData` меняю `parent.isValid()` на `!parentIsValid()`, а в методе `flags` возвращаю при невалидном индексе `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled`, то курсор показывает, что перетаскивание возможно в любой части view, но только не в уже существующий элемент. Где я ошибся?

UDP потестив немного я понял, что drop на самом деле работает, а проблема заключается в другом (не в модели). Если при первом наведении во view мышь не попала на элемент, то метод `canDropMimeData` вызывается только один раз и сколько мы не двигаем мышь - он вызываться не будет. Но если первый раз мы попали на элемент, то вызов происходит при каждом движении мыши. Извиняюсь если описал не понятно, потому что я и сам не понимаю, как такое вообще проиходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, в чем оказалась проблема: я использовал свой унаследованный от qmimedata класс, который не использовал метод setdata, в результате чего, при проверке dragenterevent не сходились типы моего mime и того, что может обрабатывать модель. Но! Несмотря на это, в этом случае (конкретно для dragenterevent), проверка на этом не заканчивается, а передаеться методу модели candropdata. Как результат - неожиданное (противоречивое) поведение программы.